# Swagger UI hide AspNetCore.Mvc.ProblemDetails schema .net 5,6 and 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger, .net-5

How to hide `ProblemDetails` Schema (see bellow) in .net 5,6 and 7.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A solution to this is to `SuppressMapClientErrors` with `ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions` in `Startup.cs`, as shown below:

```cs
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers().ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(x => { x.SuppressMapClientErrors = true; });
    ...
}
```